# Spring Data Elasticsearch containing query with spaces

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have an entity named `Port` with a field `portName`. I wrote following Spring Data ES query method for `containing` query:

```
List<Port> ports = portRepository.findByPortNameContaining(searchText);
```

It is working fine until the `searchText` doesn't contain any spaces. If it does, I get the following error:

```
"Cannot constructQuery '*\"sample port\"*'. Use expression or multiple clauses instead."
```

When I try Spring Data ES `search` method as:

```
List<Port> ports = Lists.newArrayList(portRepository.search(
            queryStringQuery(searchText)
                    .field("portName")
    ));
```

If I have a port named `Loui Kentucky`, I am only able to get results when the `searchText` is exactly a complete word like `Loui` or `Kentucky` or `Loui Kentucky`. Same happens with `analyzeWildcard`:

```
List<Port> ports = Lists.newArrayList(portRepository.search(
       boolQuery().should(queryStringQuery(searchText).analyzeWildcard(true).field("portName"))
    ));
```

I want to construct a simple containing query which can handle spaces as well. No fuzziness. Search results should appear even when I search for `i K` as `Loui Kentucky` contains that substring.

Comment: ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43182552/spring-data-api-containing-or-startwith-not-working-with-space-which-has-wildc